# How to activate Faces configuration editor in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jsf, faces-config

When I make a JSF2.0 project in eclipse, the opening of it's faces-config.xml file always starts the faces configuration editor. But now I have a Google AppEngine project and I have added JSF2 (and PrimeFaces) manually. And when I open the faces-config.xml file, the faces configuration editor doesn't start so I can edit this file only through xml source.

How can I activate the Faces Configuration Editor for this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the JSF facet in the *Project Facets* section of the project's properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to achieve this, get the JBoss Tools 3.2.2 plugin from

> http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios/

(paste the link in eclipse, go to Help -> Install New Software) this is the link to  for eclipse Helios , but you can for any other eclipse too (including Indigo)

all you need to select from the package is Web and Java EE Development

Than right click your WEB-INF folder which inside the war folder, then select New - > Faces Config and type the name of file as faces-config

That's it (checked myself just now)